# Stack Exchange pinned sites disappear on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, communities-list

When I view all my pinned sites, if I move an item down or up the list, the other items I pass over disappear like so:

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a fun bug!

This has been fixed as of version 1.0.69 (coming out in the next day or two), thanks for spotting it!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the information, i'll update as soon as it gets on the play store!